# NSMutableDictionary updates not working in UItableview

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I'm using  ***NSMutableDictionary *articleDictionary*** as a datasource for tableview.I have different tab in tableview page, each tab i'm using different xml file  [https://domain.com/api/categories/3/user/xml ] . I received different set of values in **(void)viewDidUnload**   area but not reflect in table view .Tableview still showing old values.Please help me . Thanks

```
 self.articleDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Comment: Have you tried *[_myTableView reloadData]* if you created the Table View manually, or *[self.tableView reloadData]* if you're in a UITableViewController ?

Comment: i'm using [self.myTableView reloadData];  in - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.
I changed my UiviewController superclass to **UITableViewController**. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering reload of the table view when you are done with parsing. That is reload the table from the same method where you update your NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Call `[self.tableView reloadData];`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the `tableview` to update. The `tableview` can't guess that your value has been updated ;)

Something like that should help

```
// Update your files normally...
// ...
// Trigger the reload
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put ample debugging stuff into your table view controller class.
Here are some pointers:

- When you call reloaddata, do you observe how many times tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath get called? Do you get proper index values there?
- Have you updated your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: to reflect change in data source? ie the latest NSMutableDictionary count?
- In your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, put NSLog about NSMutableDictionary to see if it reflects the latest status?